# pyinstaller issue with path and icons

Tags: python, pyinstaller

How do I run my pyinstaller created script if it depends on functions stored in a different file?

I have a file, let's call file.py and in it, it has:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'Functions')
from getDigits import getDigits
```

In my pyinstaller executable script that I create, it runs file.py and file2.py but only file.py uses the import getDigits function.

`My error code is: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'getDigits'` even when I place the getDigits file in the same directory as the executable.

Do I need to use the full path or something and if so, how do I go about accomplishing this?

Also, another question how do I go about using icons for excutable: I used the following but it still doesn't show my executable file with desired icon. I have a folder.ico in the same directory.

`pyinstaller --onefile --icon=folder.ico run_files.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyInstaller can't see path manipulations. Add each extra path when building with the `-p <path>` option.

In your case `-p path/to/script/directory/Functions`.